# Is there a way to convert VirtualBox .vdi harddisk from SATA to SCSI?

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, sata, scsi

I have a virtualbox virtual `SATA` harddrive and need to convert it to `SCSI` (`lsi`). Is there a possibility how to do it with `VBoxManage`? I cannot find it in the documentation. I've also tried it by converting it to vmware `vmdk` as described [here](https://www.virtualtothecore.com/en/convert-a-virtual-disk-from-ide-to-scsi/) with no luck.

Comment: I suggest [edit]ing your question and provide details about what you're trying to achieve and why. As it is it looks like an X-Y problem.

Comment: The customer I am providing the virtual disk to needs them to be SCSI because of some backup jobs that are not working properly on SATA drives.   So it is quite artificial problem, but there is a real problem behind it.

Comment: In a VM they are neither one or another, that's just how the virtualization software interprets them. If it can be changed it must be at the virtualization software settings.

Comment: So what you are saying is that it should be possible just to connect the virtual disk to different controller added to the VM? I've tried and it doesn't work.

Comment: I only use Virtualbox. In VB you can add different controllers but if already installed in a virtual SATA drive that can't be changed (and that's the default). What can be done is setting the OS virtual hard drive with the intended controller *before* installing the OS.

Comment: Yes, that one I figured out, but I've put quite some work into the VM, so I was trying to come up with something that would not require to do it all again. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Perhaps this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30488640/virtualbox-how-to-move-hard-drive-from-one-controller-to-another

Comment: I've tried that, the system (centos) strarts booting up, but it is terribly slow and it never finishes loading.